# How can I detect when an AngularJS app is finished loading a page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, selenium, robotframework

I'm trying to write Robot Framework tests to cover certain use cases for a third party AngularJS app.

I have the requirement that I need to use Python 3.5+ and SeleniumLibrary (rather than the old Selenium2Library).

I've attempted to adapt the wait_until_angular_ready keyword from https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-extendedselenium2library to work outside of the context of this library, updating it to work with Python 3.5+ and SeleniumLibrary.

The keyword executes the following JavaScript to check when Angular is Ready, but it seems to always return true immediately

```
var cb = arguments[arguments.length-1];
if(window.angular){
  var $inj;
  try {
    $inj = angular.element(document.querySelector('[data-ng-app],[ng-app],.ng-scope')
      ||document).injector()
      ||angular.injector(['ng'])
  } catch(ex) {
    $inj = angular.injector(['ng'])
  };
  $inj.get = $inj.get||$inj;
  $inj.get('$browser').notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(function() {
    cb(true) // it's always returning here
  })
} else {
  cb(true)
}
```

This is called from within my version of the wait_until_angular_ready keyword which is located in a class which subclasses the SeleniumLibrary WaitingKeywords class.

The code which executes the Js looks like

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100, 0.1). \
  until(lambda driver: driver.execute_async_script(script), error)
```

Have I made a mistake here or is this not the correct way to check when angular has finished rendering the page?  I will admit that I am not very familiar with AngularJS

Comment: This is not a correct question because there's no specific moment 'when angular has finished rendering'. E.g. a dashboard that constantly refreshes graphs, when does it finish rendering? It always depends on particular case, but *most times* there's some initial state that can be waited for. It cannot be tracked. You can use some generic techniques, like waiting for window `load` event, checking  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver every second or so until the page is stable, etc.

Comment: Well, there must be some way of doing it, otherwise how does https://github.com/rickypc/robotframework-extendedselenium2library work?

Comment: By using generic techniques similar to the ones I've listed, notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests  is one of them. There's no accurate way to do this. All of them will fail if there's no specific initial state the page renders to, like in dashboard example. Usually in e2e/acceptance testing you should worry not about app state (Angular app may be initialized but directives you're after may not) but poll DOM for particular elements (see how Protractor tests are written, for example).

Comment: In your code `||angular.injector(['ng'])`, `catch(ex) {
    $inj = angular.injector(['ng']) }` and `else { cb(true) }` pieces will cause false positives. This won't work if the app is in production mode.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you resolved this issue, but if anyone in the future have the same inconvenience can use this library for Angular in Robot framework: https://github.com/Selenium2Library/robotframework-angularjs

Answer (score -1):

you can use **document.readyState** , it will **return "complete"** as a response if the page is rendered completly.

Comment: @Kittenmittons : could you please try this ...?